# Dual monitors with different PPIs

Tags: macbook

Specifically I'm using my MacBook Pro Retina and another 1080p monitor.

However the scaling on the secondary monitor seems to match the primary monitor, causing any windows on the secondary monitor to be scaled up and look extremely large.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to have different scaling factors for each display. It will be addressed in a future version of elementary OS after the move from X11 to Wayland as the display server